# photoBox not showing on .Show()

Tags: c#, winforms

When the following function is called, it is not showing the corresponding photoBoxes.  I've done a debugging walkthrough, it even reaches the parts necessary to Show() and Hide().  I don't know what I can do.  It's not showing anything

```
public void SmokerTakeIngredientFromTable(agents agent, List<smokers> smoker)
{
   int index = 0;
   bool smoker_takes_ingredients = false;
   while (!smoker_takes_ingredients)
   {
      if ((smoker[index].item != agent.item_1) && (smoker[index].item != agent.item_2))
      {
         if (index == 0)
         {
            leftarrow_img.Show();
            rightarrow_img.Hide();
            downarrow_img.Hide();
         }
         else if (index == 1)
         {
            leftarrow_img.Hide();
            rightarrow_img.Show();
            downarrow_img.Hide();
         }
         else if (index == 2)
         {
            leftarrow_img.Hide();
            rightarrow_img.Hide();
            downarrow_img.Show();
         }
         agent.item_1 = 3;
         agent.item_2 = 3;
         break;
      }
      index++;
   }
}
```

This is what the designer for these photoBoxes look like:

[image]

This is the properties page for one of the photoBoxes (they are all identical apart from the actual image file, they all have Visible = false too)

[image]

Comment: Is there a panel or other container control that needs to be shown as well?

Comment: Why don't you make everything visible at first and then try to hide it? Just do it step by step.

Comment: I got it to work now, apparently I had to refresh the form every time I change visibility of certain controls.

Answer (score 0):

When making visibility changes I need to refresh the form using `this.Refresh()`

Comment: If you would like to, you can mark this as the accepted answer to indicate that this is the solution to your problem by clicking on the outline of a checkbox to the left of the answer.

Comment: It won't let me for 2 days

Comment: Right, sorry, forgot about that.